# Conditional expectation of a Poisson random variable: confusing sums

Tags: probability-theory

In *Probabilty and Random Processes* by Grimmett and Stirzaker, the following example is given (page 68):

[image]

My question is: how are the last three (math) lines true? Specifically, how do these two sums simplify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional distribution of $N$ given that $K = k$ is a *Poisson* distribution with parameter $q\lambda$ *but displaced $k$ to the right;* that is, (conditionally) $N$ is of the form $M+k$ where $M$ is Poisson$(q\lambda)$ and so $$E[N\mid K = k] = E[M+k] = E[M]+k = q\lambda + k.$$

Or, without spending time thinking about the matter, write $m = n-k$ and the sum as
$$\begin{align}E[N\mid K = k] &= \sum_{n\geq k}n \frac{(q\lambda)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}e^{-q\lambda}\\
&= \sum_{m \geq 0} (m+k)\frac{(q\lambda)^{m}}{m!}e^{-q\lambda}\\
&= \sum_{m \geq 0}m\frac{(q\lambda)^{m}}{m!}e^{-q\lambda}
+ k \sum_{m \geq 0}\frac{(q\lambda)^{m}}{m!}e^{-q\lambda}\\
& = q\lambda + k
\end{align}$$
where I will leave how the very last line follows from
the previous one as a puzzle for you to work out.

Comment: Thanks Dilip. One question though. It makes sense why N (conditioned by K) has a parameter that is displaced by k, since there must be at least k eggs because k have hatched. But why does the parameter have the probability that an egg hasn't hatched (q) times lamda? Does this come from the fact that the remaining eggs haven't hatched? If so, how? You have answered my question in math, but I do not understand intuitively.

Comment: @ziz  Roughly speaking, we expect a _fraction_ $p$ of the eggs to have hatched and fraction $q = 1-p$ of the eggs to not have hatched. Thus, the number $K$ of chicks should be Poisson distributed with parameter $p\lambda$ while the number $U$ of unhatched eggs should be Poisson with parameter $q\lambda$. $K$ and $U$ are _unconditionally_ independent (Poisson) random variables and their sum $N = K+U$ is Poisson too.  But given $N$, $K$ and $U$ are _conditionally dependent_ **binomial** random variables. As G&S point out, given $K$ (or $U$), the other is a displaced Poisson random variable.